# Passing Parameteres to Interactive script programatically

Tags: perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures, expect.pm

We have an interactive script(Script 1)  which asks for an IP Address and continues it's execution process. Script 1 is called from script2. 
 As we know the IP address we want to pass IP Automatically to script so that manual intervention is not required

I looked into Expect Module. But i cannot install that module in PRODUCTION server.

Can someone suggest a way to overcome this issue.

Comment: Rewrite script 1 so that it takes a parameter rather than being interactive.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Unless it does something funky, just piping might work: `script2.pl | scrpit1.pl`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
#script2.pl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;

GetOptions (
"ipAddress=s" => \$ip,
) or die("Enter IP address");

my $cmd = "perl script1.pl --ip=$ip";
system($cmd);
```

.

```
#script1.pl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;
GetOptions (
"ip=s" => \$ip,
) or die("Enter IP address");

print "IP address is $ip";
```

Execute like this.

```
perl script2.pl --ipAddress=10.11.12.13
```

If you want to execute script1 directly,  can execute like this,

```
perl script1.pl --ip=10.11.12.13
```